# Remove scroll bar for 100% zoom

Tags: html, css, datatables

I want to display a complete data table but because the columns are pretty large in amount and the table is set to non-responsive. if I zoom to 80% all table content is clearly visible to me without a horizontal scroll bar but if I reset to 100%  few of my columns are not visible until I scroll to right. what can I do in this case?

[image]

Comment: please add your relevant code

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML where you create your table, set the width to 100%.

```html
<table id="my-table" class="some-class" style="width: 100%;">
</table>
```